# SQLAlchemy don't create tables if using Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-restplus

I'm trying to create a project using `Flask`, `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, `flask-restplus` and `marshmallow` (tried with `flask-marshmallow` too), but the integration of these tools does not work very well.
Everytime I include some new lib, a new error occur.

I already give up to use `migrations` with `Flask-SQLAlchemy` because for some reason, this thing don't work. But now, the problem is with `marshmallow`.

I'm trying to make with modules and I think this is the part of the problem (all examples of Flask-SQLAlchmey, flask-restplus, flask-marshmallow, etc put everything in a single file)

This is my **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

import settings
from api import api
from database import init_database, reset_database

app = Flask(__name__)


def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = settings.SERVER_ADDRESS
    flask_app.secret_key = settings.SECRET_KEY


def initialize_app(flask_app):
    configure_app(flask_app)

    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix=settings.URL_PREFIX)
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    # api.add_namespace(auth_login_namespace)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

    init_database(flask_app)
    if settings.DEBUG:
        reset_database(flask_app)


def main():
    initialize_app(app)
    app.run(debug=settings.DEBUG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`api/__init__.py`:

```
import settings

from flask_restplus import Api

api = Api(
    version='1.0',
    title='Test',
    description='Some description'
)


@api.errorhandler
def default_error_handler(e):
    message = 'An unhandled exception occurred.'

    if not settings.DEBUG:
        return {'message': message}, 500
```

`database/__init__.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import settings

db = SQLAlchemy()


def init_database(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = settings.DATABASE_URI
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    global db # I really don't like this! :(
    db = SQLAlchemy(flask_app)


def reset_database(flask_app):
    from database.models import User
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(User(username='admin', email='abc@def.com', name='admin', password='123', admin=True)
    db.session.commit()
```

I have my app, with only one `model` until now:

`database/models/User.py`:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from sqlalchemy import func

from database import db


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())


class UserSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    username = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    name = fields.Str()
    password = fields.Str()
    admin = fields.Bool()
    created_on = fields.DateTime()
```

now, if I use the following code (this code is called everytime my app start on debug mode, on function `reset_database`, in file **database/__init__.py**):

```
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
db.session.add(User(username='admin', email='abc@def.com', name='admin', password='123', admin=True)
db.session.commit()
```

the `User` table is not created, and the `admin` is not inserted on table, because the table don't exist (`db.create_all()` don't create anything).

`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user`.

For some reason, if I remove the class `UserSchema` (on **database/models/User.py**), the `db.create_all()` function create the table).

Comment: Please add your app.py to your question and add import commands into your examples, I think I have a solution.

Comment: @Fian, I have update the question with imports and app.py. The question become longer, but I think I put everything that you need!

Comment: Are you sure you have module `database/models/User.py` and not `database/models.py` ?

Comment: @Fian, yes, absolutely sure! in `database` folder, I have a `__init__.py` with codes above, and in this folder, I have another folder named `models`. Inside this `models` folder, I have `__init.py__` with blank content, and a `User.py` with the code above. In `reset_database` function, tried to change the `import` to `from database.models.User import User` and got same error.

Comment: Could you try changing file's name from `User.py` to `user_module.py` and line `from database.models import User` to `from database.models.user_module import User` and test again? Does the error persists?

Comment: same error! `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user`. in `reset_database` tried with `with app.app_context():` too, like http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.app_context, but no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146548/discussion-between-fian-and-roberto-correia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got working right now:

on `database/__init__.py`, altered the `init_database` function to:

```
def init_database(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = settings.DATABASE_URI
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(flask_app)
```

and in `database/reset_database.py`:

```
def reset_database(flask_app):
    with flask_app.app_context():
        from database.models.user_module import User
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        db.session.add(User(username='admin', email='abc@def.com', name='admin', password='123', admin=True))
        db.session.commit()
```

The problems was the `init_app`, use the `app_context`, and I'm importing the wrong `User` module (tks Fian)